# How to handle errors in Grails ng-domain?

Tags: angularjs, grails

grails create-ng-domain provides the code below?

```
angular
.module("app.subscription")
.factory("LaunchSubscription", LaunchSubscription);

function LaunchSubscription($resource) {
    var LaunchSubscription = $resource(
        "api/launchSubscription/:id",
        {"id": "@id"},
        {"update": {method: "PUT"}, "list": {method: "GET", isArray: true}}
    );
    return LaunchSubscription;
}
```

In the controller.js, how do I handle errors when calling $save? It currently looks like this.

```
launch.subscribe = function (){
    launch.newSubscription.$save({}, function() {
        launch.newSubscription = new LaunchSubscription();
        launch.subscribed = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by errors? Which errors you are talking about? Are they Grails validation errors?

Comment: Yes. Error response sent back from the server.